# How to restart FireFox browser in iMacros

Tags: javascript, firefox, batch-file, imacros

How can I restart the FireFox browser in iMacros and reduce RAM consumption. And also that iMacros continues from where it left of or at least start again the .js script?

Is there a batch solution for this?

Comment: Take a look at programs like Boxoft(http://www.boxoft.com/folder-watcher/), they monitor files.  Write to a file when you want to restart Firefox, the Boxoft program can kick off a batch file to close Firefox and Restart it.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. If it's some low RAM solution I will use it.